# Python shell Restarting while executing MainWindow=QtGui.QMainWindow()

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

The problem that i am having is my python shell restarts as it starts executing SetupUi()

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
   def __init__(self):
      print "control"
      self.setupUi()
   def setupUi(self):
      print "control"
      MainWindow=QtGui.QMainWindow()
      print "control"
      MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
      print "control"
      MainWindow.resize(790, 610)
      print "control"
```

The print "control" is just to see where the execution is going wrong , i did this because while execution no error is shown  and the shell just restarts.

here are the imports

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys
import sqlite3
```

Comment: I suggest you go through the tutorial carefully. http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/designer.html

Comment: define 'restarts' - the python process ends and then spawns itself again? I somehow doubt that...

Comment: thanx guys for helping
i didnt execute
    app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

thanx for responding so fast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i got it the problem was that i didn't execute

```
app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
```

damm me